# encode and decode in android studio

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, decode, encode

i am trying to make converter by getting input from editText then encode it and get back decoded value. i want to do this on editText event or if not possible then on button click event? 
complete this code please

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


      String  text = Base64.encodeToString(ed1.getText().toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT );
      String  text2 = new String( Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT ) );

    }
}
```

Comment: get input in EditText ed1 and result in ed2

Comment: what exactly do you expect as result?

Comment: if you are encoding the string then decoding the and displaying the decoded result. What the purpose encode and decode string?

Comment: Read this it will help for edit text change event you have to encode at your own method Base64 or with algoritham https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: And what has all this to do with android studio?